# Serious Problem after upgrading to ubuntu 14.04 to 13.10 while booting

Tags: boot, upgrade

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu partition from 13.10 to 14.04. After the upgrade I rebooted the system and got the following error message whilst booting:

```
Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /. 
Press. I to ignore, S to skip mounting, or M for manual recovery.
```

As I'm not very skilled in manually recovering data in Ubuntu I could not do very much but to skip mounting and to wait for the system to boot, which it did partially but failed to load some kernel packages. Eventually I just get a black screen and am only left with rebooting the system again. Anyone got the same problem or knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's ./temp which is not found.

Comment: I tried that now, manually fixing the error via fsck, but it doesn't work for me. It says: fsck: fsck.ntfs: not found

Comment: I don't get an error notification if use the option fsck -A instead, but after rebooting I still have the same problem.

Comment: Okay, sorry that didn't work. I did find [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217829&p=12996954#post12996954) discussion of your issue. Haven't tested these solutions myself but they may be useful to you.

Comment: No problem, it was a better suggestion than the things I tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the discussion. Unfortunately I cannot use the 'e'-option before starting to boot, so I couldn't follow the other instructions mentioned there. Nevertheless, thank you for the link.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, at least you can hold shift while booting to get past this annoying error. (accord to my link above)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! That's exactly it: By holding shift I can enter the advanced options menu and can reset the read only mode ro to a read and write mode rw. As is described in the ubuntu forum threads, you just need to change the ro option in the lupin_10 file in the grup-d folder.

Comment: You're welcome!! I moved my answer into an actual answer for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift during boot to enter advanced options and reset the read mode like in this: 
[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217829&p=12996954#post12996954)

Moved into an answer for clarity's sake for future readers and so it can be **answered**.